# spring boot calling thymeleaf template failed

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

im getting this error i searched on the same issues like mine on stack and i have foudn that i shouldn t put .html when calling it but im getting the same error :

```
`Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "orderConfirmationEmailTemplate", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolver`s
```

my mail constructor :

```
@Component
public class MailConstructor {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public SimpleMailMessage constructNewUserEmail(User user, String password) {
        String message="\nPlease use the following credentials to log in and edit your personal information including your own password."
                + "\nUsername:"+user.getUsername()+"\nPassword:"+password;

        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
        email.setTo(user.getEmail());
        email.setSubject("Le's Bookstore - New User");
        email.setText(message);
        email.setFrom(env.getProperty("support.email"));
        return email;
    }

    public MimeMessagePreparator constructOrderConfirmationEmail (User user, Order order, Locale locale) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("order", order);
        context.setVariable("user", user);
        context.setVariable("cartItemList", order.getCartItemList());
        String text = templateEngine.process("orderConfirmationEmailTemplate.html", context);

        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            @Override
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper email = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                email.setTo(user.getEmail());
                email.setSubject("Order Confirmation - "+order.getId());
                email.setText(text,true);
                email.setFrom(new InternetAddress("alaaeddinezammel1993@gmail.com"));
            }
        };

        return messagePreparator;
    }
```

and im calling it from rest service:

```
mailSender.send(mailConstructor.constructOrderConfirmationEmail(user, order, Locale.ENGLISH));

    shoppingCartService.clearShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
```

and im putting the file .html under package in the project

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually with my configuration putted in my question i just put the .html file under file called templates under resources and it works the mail is sent , spring boot is apparently auto configured with this path without configuring the 
templateResolver

[image]

Comment: The TemplateResolver which Spring Boot auto configures resolves templates from the /templates folder so putting your template in that folder allows you to use the default configuration

Answer (score 1):

In your question, the `TemplateEngine` is auto wired so I cannot see how it is configured but it in order to discover your template from the location `com.bookstore.domain.security.templates` the configuration should look something like this:

```
@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix(“/com/bookstore/domain/security/templates“);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    …
    return templateResolver;
}
```

In this code I am configuring the `TemplateEngine` in code, perhaps you are using XML. Regardless of how you are configuring the TemplateEngine, you are clearly using Spring to do so (since you inject it into your `MailConstructor`), the key point here is that regardless of **how** you configure it you need to tell it where to find your template and the way to do that is to invoke the `ITemplateResolver`'s `setPrefix()` method.

Plenty more details in the article titled [Sending email in Spring with Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html) in the Thymeleaf docs.

Comment: Regardless of **how** you configure your TemplateResolver the key point is that you need to tell it where to find your template and the way to do that is to invoke the ITemplateResolver's setPrefix() method. See the link I provided to the Thymeleaf docs for a working example.